# Unable to load library NLPIR.dll in JNA

Tags: java, jna

I try to use a word-segmentation software, I create a new java project named `JNA`, and import the required files into `JNA` dir, then I try to run it without any code modification, and MyEclipse warns me that:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'E://java//JNI//JnaTest_NLPIR//NLPIR': Native library (win32-x86-64/E://java//JNI//JnaTest_NLPIR//NLPIR.dll) not found in resource path ([file:/D:/javasoft/MyEclipse_workspace/JNA/bin/, file:/D:/javasoft/MyEclipse_workspace/JNA/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar])`

I tried to:

- create the same dirs and move `NLPIR.dll` to `E:/java/JNI/JnaTest_NLPIR/`, it didn't work.
- move `NLPIR.dll` directly to `JNA/bin` or `JNA/lib`, but it didn't work, too.

I think that it is caused by the position of my `NLPIR.dll`. But I could not figure out how to fix it.

I would be grateful for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `NLPIR.dll` (and all its dependent libraries) is on `%PATH%`, or use `-Djna.library.path=...` to indicate the folder it's in.

Comment: I added `NLPIR.dll` to my `PATH`,and modified `dll_or_so_path` in file `nlpir.properties` in project dir to `dll_or_so_path=D:/javasoft/MyEclipse_workspace/JNA/NLPIR.dll`. then the problem gone, but another came: `%1 not a valid Win32 application `. I use 64bit MyEclipse, is that the cause? I have seen some answer that the problem could be solved by changing MyEclipse to 32bit.....

Comment: If your library is 32-bit, you must use a 32-bit JVM.  The architecture of your DLL must match that of your JVM.